# R Dataframe - Find value of a column corresponding to values in another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame containing many columns and I want to query data in a particular row of a column (say row1, column A) corresponding to value in another column (row1, column B).

How is this done in R?

Comment: `df[df$A == 'something',]`...

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please give a [mre] in your question!

Comment: Maybe? `df1$colA[ 1 ] == df1$colB[ 1 ]`

Comment: to add further, suppose we have two columns A and b , as shown:

Comment: means, i have two columns- "value" and "day"". i need to create a new column "previous day average"which would use the excel formula of AVERAGEIFS to select the value from "value" column and from Day Column criteria is day<- day -1, i.e I need to find the value for previous day